# What is the anime that is set in the most distant future of today?

Tags: anime-history

A lot of anime set in the distant future doesn't specify the calendar year, so it ends up with something like *"Before the..."* or *"XX years ago"*.

Some of the future-themed anime such as *Gundam* and *Dragon Ball* have their own calendar era which is Universal Century and Age respectively. We can't convert or compare the alternate calendar of the Anime to our real-life Gregorian calendar, so it might be helpful if the Anime has a similar calendar to ours.

According to my research, *Legend of the Galactic Heroes* is the anime that is set in the most distant future as of today, in AD 2801.

Comment: Blame! is set in _really_ distant future. Although, currently existing anime, based on this manga, can be barely called full-fledged adaptation, it is more of proof of concept.

Comment: Space Pirate Captain Harlock, a 1978 anime TV series, is set in 2977 AD.  Legend of the Galactic Heroes is actually set in 3596 AD, 2801 AD is a historical date when the "Space Era" replaced the Gregorian calendar. I don't think this question is going to have an easy and definitive answer. It's likely the correct answer is something like an obscure anime set in the year 234,567 AD, a fact which is only revealed by a calendar in the background art of an otherwise unremarkable scene.

Comment: I'm sure there are anime set way beyond a mere 2808, and this is becoming more like a list question now with the listing of series that do not occur in the most distant future.

Comment: What is interesting about this question? Perhaps there exists some little-known anime that is set in the year 109810712619675824, but, like, so what? (Also - this question is borderline an out-of-universe list question, which I think we're generally not fond of.)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like *Legend of the Galactic Heroes* is the Anime that is set in the most distant future (AD 3596). You can squeeze it in or append the list if you found any Anime that is set in the era between the Anime(s) or further.

- **Blue Gender**
  Yuji wakes up from cryogenic sleep in 2031 and the story begins.
- **Evangelion 3.0**
  The events of Evangelion 3.0 occur in 2032, [14 years](http://wiki.evageeks.org/Evangelion_3.0#Operation_US.2C_Wille.2C_and_the_AAA_Wunder) after Evangelion 2.0 ([Assumed in 2018](http://wiki.evageeks.org/Neon_Genesis_Evangelion_Timeline#2007_or_2018.3F)).
- **Ghost in the Shell: S.A.C. Solid State Society**
  The most distant timeline in the series take place in year 2034.
- **Guilty Crown**
  The main story starts 10 years after the [Lost Christmas](http://guiltycrown.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Christmas) incident on the Christmas eve in 2029. So it's 2039.
- **Voices of a Distant Star**
  The story begins in 2047.
- **Freezing**
  In 2065, Earth is in the middle of a war with extra-dimensional aliens called Nova.
- **Psycho-Pass**
  The main events of the first two seasons of Psycho-Pass span the years 2112-2114.
- **Infinite Ryvius**
  Set in the year 2225, mankind has spread from Earth to inhabit nearly all the planets or nearby moons in colonies and settlements.
- **Lily C.A.T.**
  The year is 2264 when the space exploration begins for the main cast.
- **Gundam 00**
  The series is set in 2307 AD. Gundam 00 is the only Gundam based in the AD/CE timeline.
- **Expelled from Paradise**
  Set in the year [2400 AD](http://rakuen-tsuiho.com/story.php#TEXT_STORY3).
- **Cyber City Oedo 808**
  Set in the year 2808 in the city of Oedo (Tokyo).
- **Legend of the Galactic Heroes**
  Set in 3596, Space Era calendar replacing the Gregorian calendar, with 2801 AD now being SE 1.

Comment: All of those dates only have four digits. Vampire Hunter D (1985) takes place in the year 12,090 A.D. The sequel from around 15 years later is set even farther into the future and ends with another time skip of 50 years or so.

Comment: Godzilla: Planet of the Monsters is set 20,000 years after the planet was taken over by Godzilla, so at least 22,000 A.D.

Answer (score 2):

- **Ergo Proxy**: Year set in 7207,It is the only anime that is set in the most far-distant future (Excluding the other Animes). The story takes place in the year 7207 where earth takes more than a thousand years to recover from a Global environmental disaster
- **Land of the lustrous**: (Unspecified) The anime is set in a Far, Distant future where the earth is struck by meteorite 6 times, ravaging it in the process.
- **Legend of the Galactic Heroes**: Set in 3596
- **Girls last tour**: some post-apocalyptic dystopian anime, No doubt the anime year is likely set in 3230 (As given by the camera of Kanazawa), where Yuri and Chito continues their journey at the near ending of the world
- **Nausicaä of the Valley of the Wind**: c.3118
- **Harlock Space Pirate**: AD 2977
- **Cyber city oedo 808**: Set in Year AD 2808 at Futuristic Tokyo, Japan
- **Halo Legends**: The story is set in year 2775 Which follows Different timelines in the galaxy
- **GUNNM**: 29th century. This anime has a lot of timelines in the future
- **Dirty pair flash**: Year 2248
- ***Megazone 23***: The story takes place in More than 500 years in the future
- **BlazBlue: Alter Memory**: Set in the year December 2199
- **Dirty Pair Project Eden**: Set in year A.D 2141
- **Ultraviolet Code:044**: Set in 2140
- **Darling in the Franxx**: the battle began in the year 2037 and currently set in the year 2137
- **Appleseed**: The story begins in year 2125
- **Dirty pair OVA**: Year 2118
- **The Animatrix**: Set in year 2090
- **Iroduku: The World in Colors**: It takes place in the year 2078 in which time-travel is possible.
- **Planetes**: Year 2075
- **Cowboy Bebop**: Year 2071
- **Vexille**: Year 2060 to 2067
- **Macross The Musicalture**: Year 2062
- **Macross frontier movie: The wings of goodbye**: Year 2059
- **Macross The ride**: Year 2058
- **Mardock scramble**: Set in the year 2054 in the futuristic city called "Mardock"
- **Genesis Climber Mospeada**: Set in year 2050
- **Macross Dynamite**: Year 2047
- **Armitage III**: Year 2046 takes place on a futuristic dystopian society of mars
- **Ghost in the shell Sac_2045**: Year 2045
- **Bubble gum crisis Tokyo 2040**: year 2040
- **Arpeggio of blue steel**: Year set in 2039
- **Dr.Stone**: Near future in year 2038
- **Dimension W**: In the year 2036, a fourth-dimensional axis called Dimension W is proven to exist.
- **A.I.C.O. Incarnation**: Set In The Near Future In Japan --> Year 2035

Comment: The other animes are Excluded

Answer (score 0):

I got 3 records

1. *Top Wo Nerae* series; *Gunbuster* has started in 2019 but in the end, our characters jumped 12000 years later, which is mind-blowing.
2. *Eureka Seven*; the plot goes on an unfamiliar planet but the environment can fool anybody. This anime's story goes on 10000 years ahead of our time.
3. *Uchuu Senkan Yamato*; this one is relatively close; it starts at 2199. but again there is a mysterious place where time flows 10 times faster than usual.